# Highlight active page in navigation

Tags: php, html, navigation

I'm trying to find a solution to use PHP, not jQuery, to insert an "active" class into the corresponding hyperlink of the current page, in the following HTML markup:

```
<nav class="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="/">Index</a></li>
<li><a href="/email">Email</a></li>
<li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

User on `/about` page, PHP applies class `<a class="active" href="/about">About</a>`

Is there a simple way I can do this with PHP?

Comment: Depends on whether you have some MVC or any software to build the path patterns.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to have a variable/function that contains current URI's exact part that you would like to use/distinguish by in your menu. If you "somehow" can't have it, then parsing `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` is a way to go. So, it will depend on structure of your URI, or maybe last mentioned variable will even work, depends.

Assuming you have a function `currentPage()` that returns a part of URI that is currently actual you can go with following

```
<?php
// $currentPage = currentPage();
// $currentPage = preg_replace([.............]); // ???
// $currentPage = "about"; // ?????
?>
```

So since you have `$currentPage` now you can do it with different approaches.

```
<ul>
<li><a <?php if ($currentPage === "") print('class="active"');?> href="/">Index</a></li>
<li><a <?php if ($currentPage === "email") print('class="active"');?> href="/email">Email</a></li>
<li><a <?php if ($currentPage === "about") print('class="active"');?> href="/about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

or

```
<ul>
<?php
$pages = array('' => 'Index','email' =>'Email','about'=>'About');
foreach ($pages as $page => $title) {
?>
    <li><a <?php if ($curretPage === $page) print('class="active"');?> href="<?php print('/'.$page);?>"><?php print($title);?></a></li>
<?php
}
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Approach #2 would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="<?php
     echo ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']=="/about"?"active":"inactive");
?>" href="/about">
    About 
</a>
```

Comment: Is the inactive class necessary? And what would I enter if all the hyperlinks are relative not including the domain?